# ConEmu environment variables

Tags: python, conemu

Situation:

1. script1 (written in python) run from ConEmu and set `SQLPATH` (`global`, with `setx /M` command)
2. than run script2 (written in python) from ConEmu, which runs `sqlplus` (uses `SQLPATH` environment variable)

script2 can get `SQLPATH` **only** if I run [this](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/ConEmuEnvironment#Export_variables).

```
ConEmuC /export PATH
```

which tell

```
ConEmuC: can't export environment to PID=4124, check < Inject ConEmuHk >
```

when I try to inject [ConEmuHk.dll](https://github.com/infodox/python-dll-injection) 
python process ends unexpectedly.

How can I make script2 use `SQLPATH` in this situation?

Comment: Do you really need global `setx`? Why if you want to inherit environment?

Comment: What did you suggest? I have script, that runs sqlplus multiple times. And I need SQLPATH for sqlplus in this script.

Comment: Just call set (or the python equivalent) to change environment of current process.